Jest - react-native-color-matrix-image-filters/dist/CMIFColorMatrixImageFilterNativeComponent.js: Could not find component config for native component
I have a React Native Android project and I just upgraded the react-native version from 0.72.3 to 0.74.3. After a fair amount of library upgrading, TS and Lint fixes, etc I was able to get my application to build and run fine.
Unfortunately, when I run my Jest tests I keep getting the following error:
/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/react-native/node_modules/react-native-color-matrix-image-filters/dist/CMIFColorMatrixImageFilterNativeComponent.js: Could not find component config for native component
I was also getting this error in Metro as I was trying to open the application when I wasn't on the latest version of react-native-color-matrix-image-filters. Like I mentioned earlier, if I add the latest version, my app builds and runs fine, just that the tests are failing.
I tried deleting node_modules, yarn.lock, yarn install again but it still gives me that error when I run the tests. Anyone that might have an idea why is this happening?
